# Como renderizar una columna de la libreria datatable si esa columna trae un Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Estoy intentando ordenar datos que vienen de una DB que estan en formato json con la libreria datatable. Actualmente, la tabla me la muestra asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como vemos, la columna 4 me trae los datos en json, y lo q quiero es mediante un for, ponerlos en orden con una lista ordenada.El tema está en que cuando intento parsear (JSON.parse) la columna me tira error y no se como hacerlo. Esta es una de las formas en que intenté hacerlo, pero no funciona.

```
{   
                render: function(data, type, row){
                    // console.log(row.ref_programa);
                    var infoProgramaPrueba = JSON.parse(row.ref_programa,true);
                    console.log(infoProgramaPrueba.length);
                        
                    return "<p>"+row.ref_programa+"</p>"
                        
                        
                }
            },
```

Este es el mensaje de error que me arroja por consola(console.log(infoProgramaPrueba.length)).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para console.log(row.ref_programa);

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien sabe o le pasó algo similar, agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el mensaje de error que obtienes y el resultado de `console.log(row.ref_programa);`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, ya edite la pregunta.

Comment: Quizá te lo trae como un arreglo. Prueba con: var result=["<p>"];
row.ref_programa.forEach(data => {
  result.push(data.referencia);
});
result.push("</p>"); return result.join(" ");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente, tu problema sería ordenar un array de objetos por un atributo. Lo cual puedes lograr utilizando [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare). Puedes probar haciendo lo siguiente:

```
"render": function(data, type, full, meta){
    let infoProgramaPrueba = JSON.parse(data, true);
    return infoProgramaPrueba
        .sort((a, b) => a.referencia.localeCompare(b.referencia))
        .map(p => `<p>${p.referencia}</p>`).join(',');
}
```

Por otro lado, puedes optar por unir los elementos de la manera que gustes utilizando `map()`. Ahí te puse un ejemplo.

Comment: Excelente, me funcionó!! Gracias mil ♥

Comment: @CaroS. no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada.